# AngularJS field validation expressions don't seem to work in ng-show

Tags: html, validation, angularjs

I'm struggling with AngularJS validation. Here's my [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in HTML 5 (which, due to my server-side framework, is required to be valid XML):

**[View in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abbDA/)**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="">
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ValidationTest" novalidate="novalidate">
        <input name="email" ng-model="myForm.email" type="email" required="required" />
        <div>
            Field:
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$valid">valid</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$invalid">invalid</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$pristine">pristine</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty">dirty</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            Form:
            <span ng-show="myForm.$valid">valid</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.$invalid">invalid</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.$pristine">pristine</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.$dirty">dirty</span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input.ng-valid {
    border-color: #0f0;
}
input.ng-invalid {
    border-color: #f00;
}
input.ng-pristine {
    background-color: #eef;
}
input.ng-dirty {
    background-color: #fee;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function ValidationTest($scope) {}
```

When I run this scenario, the CSS classes applied to the form element correctly reflect its validation status, as do the ng-show directives for the form. However, the ng-show directives for the field start out correct (showing "invalid" and "pristine") but all disappear once I start typing in the field. As far as I can tell, I'm doing this as the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) indicates, so what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just realized why: Both the AngularJS object representing the field and the value of the field itself were bound to the same location: `myForm.email`. The `input` element's value should have been just `email`.

Clarification as requested by Ahmad: The expression `myForm.email` refers to an object created by AngularJS to represent the `email` field in the `myForm` form. It is not the actual value of the field, which is what you're supposed to put in the `ng-model` attribute of the `<input>` element. For that, I should just specify the name of a property in the scope that I want to use to store that value. So changing `ng-model` to say just `email` instead of `myForm.email` is the fix. The scope's `email` property will then contain a string which is the value entered it in the field (when it is valid).

Comment: Could you please expand/clarify your answer?

Comment: I seem to have a similar issue, but am having difficulty with the distinction you are drawing in your answer

Comment: Added the clarification @Ahmad requested.